# How to make image smaller on desktop size screen

Tags: html, css, image, size, desktop

I am doing my project and was struggling really long with setting up my header image and to make it responsive, when finally I've done that it looks great on mobile and tablet but on desktop screen is soo huge. I am already lost and have no idea if with my responsive settings can I make that image smaller.
This is my code and print screen.

HTML

```
<header class="shape"> 
        <div>
            <img class="image-hero" src="assets/images/holiday.webp" alt="holiday">
        </div>
        
    </header>
```

CSS:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}



.image-hero {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

[print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCnrf.jpg)

I looked for any clues online, but actually now I am afraid to do anything to break everything else.

Answer (score 1):

Image is huge because the size is set to 100%. Change min-width and image size to  what you need.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
   .image-hero {
    width: 200px;
}
```

Or visa versa, set the image size you need, then do media query to adjust for mobile.

if you use persentage for the image size then it will be percentage of a parent element (header and/or div)

```
<header>
  <div>
     <img class="image-hero" src="assets/images/holiday.webp"   
       alt="holiday">
  </div>
</header>
```

Location of media query matters, add it below your code that sets image size, because media query needs to overwrite it. 
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp